# How do I measure GPU time on Metal?

Tags: profiling, metal

I want to see **programmatically** how much GPU time a part of my application consumes on macOS and iOS. On OpenGL and D3D I can use GPU timer query objects. I searched and couldn't find anything similar for Metal. How do I measure GPU time on Metal **without using Instruments** etc. I'm using Objective-C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add scheduled and completed handler blocks to a command buffer. You can take timestamps in each and compare. There's some latency, since the blocks are executed on the CPU, but it should get you close.

With Metal 2.1, Metal now provides "events", which are more like fences in other APIs. (The name `MTLFence` was already used for synchronizing shared heap stuff.) In particular, with `MTLSharedEvent`, you can encode commands to modify the event's value at particular points in the command buffer(s). Then, you can either way for the event to have that value or ask for a block to be executed asynchronously when the event reaches a target value.

That still has problems with latency, etc. (as Ian Ollmann described), but is more fine grained than command buffer scheduling and completion. In particular, as Klaas mentions in a comment, a command buffer being scheduled does not indicate that it has started executing. You could put commands to set an event's value at the beginning and (with a different value) at the end of a sequence of commands, and those would only notify at actual execution time.

Finally, on iOS 10.3+ but not macOS, `MTLCommandBuffer` has two properties, `GPUStartTime` and `GPUEndTime`, with which you can determine how much time a command buffer took to execute on the GPU. This should not be subject to latency in the same way as the other techniques.

Comment: What about (3) in the answer of @ian below? In my case of rendering to an offscreen buffer and then blitting the offscreen buffer to a drawable both scheduled handlers get called first and then both completed handlers get called afterwards. There is no way to figure out which one took what time.

Comment: @Klaas Yes, Ian is correct. I've also updated my answer with some other techniques.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of problems with this method:

1) You really want to know what is the GPU side latency within a command buffer most of the time, not round trip to CPU.    This is better measured as the time difference between running 20 instances of the shader and 10 instances of the shader. However, that approach can add noise since the error is the sum of the errors associated with the two measurements.

2) Waiting for completion causes the GPU to clock down when it stops executing. When it starts back up again, the clock is in a low power state and may take quite a while to come up again, skewing your results. This can be a serious problem and may understate your performance in benchmark vs. actual by a factor of two or more.

3) if you start the clock on scheduled and stop on completed, but the GPU is busy running other work, then your elapsed time includes time spent on the other workload. If the GPU is not busy, then you get the clock down problems described in (2).

This problem is considerably harder to do right than most benchmarking cases I've worked with, and I have done a lot of performance measurement.

The best way to measure these things is to use on device performance monitor counters, as it is a direct measure of what is going on, using the machine's own notion of time. I favor ones that report cycles over wall clock time because that tends to weed out clock slewing, but there is not universal agreement about that. (Not all parts of the hardware run at the same frequency, etc.) I would look to the developer tools for methods to measure based on PMCs and if you don't find them, ask for them.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Ken's comment above, `GPUStartTime` and `GPUEndTime` is now available on macOS too (10.15+):
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcommandbuffer/1639926-gpuendtime?language=objc